# MDX Aggregated Row (display subtotals on the columns)

Tags: mdx

I have a very simple MDX query.

```
SELECT 
    NON EMPTY {[Measures].[ing_pc_hh_presupuestadas], horas,[Measures].[ing_pc_hh_faltantes],[Measures].[ing_pc_faltante] }
    ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY CROSSJOIN([proyecto].[codigo proyecto].[All].CHILDREN, [proyecto].[descripcion proyecto].[All].CHILDREN, [concepto].[descripcion concepto].[All].CHILDREN)
    ON ROWS
    FROM
        [TACO V1]
    WHERE 
        {([concepto].[id concepto].&[1]) , ([concepto].[id concepto].&[5])}
```

This is the idea. A project has 2 concepts. So, in this query, I visualize some measures for each project and concept. This is fine. But I need an extra row for each project, with  summarized values for each measure.

This image is the actual scenario:
[image]

I need to see the second scenario for each project (here is an example for one project)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH MEMBER [proyecto].[codigo proyecto].[ Subtotal] AS ' SUM( { [proyecto].[codigo proyecto].[All].CHILDREN }) ', SOLVE_ORDER = 1000 

MEMBER [proyecto].[descripcion proyecto].[ Subtotal] AS ' SUM( { [proyecto].[descripcion proyecto].[All].CHILDREN }) ', SOLVE_ORDER = 1000

MEMBER [proyecto].[descripcion concepto].[ Subtotal] AS ' SUM( { [proyecto].[descripcion concepto].[All].CHILDREN }) ', SOLVE_ORDER = 1000

SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[ing_pc_hh_presupuestadas], horas,[Measures].[ing_pc_hh_faltantes],[Measures].[ing_pc_faltante] }
    ON COLUMNS,

NON EMPTY { { 

{ { [proyecto].[codigo proyecto].[ Subtotal] }, { [proyecto].[codigo proyecto].[All].CHILDREN } } 

* { { [proyecto].[descripcion proyecto].[ Subtotal] }, { [proyecto].[descripcion proyecto].[All].CHILDREN } } 

* { { [proyecto].[descripcion concepto].[ Subtotal] }, { [proyecto].[descripcion concepto].[All].CHILDREN } } 

} } ON ROWS
FROM
        [TACO V1]
    WHERE 
        {([concepto].[id concepto].&[1]) , ([concepto].[id concepto].&[5])}
```

Comment: Hello!!!!Thanks a lot for your solution.
I make a little changes to your solutions, and works perfectly.

{ { [proyecto].[codigo proyecto].[All].CHILDREN } } 

* { [proyecto].[descripcion proyecto].[All].CHILDREN } 

* { { [concepto].[descripcion concepto].[ Subtotal] }, { [concepto].[descripcion concepto].[All].CHILDREN } } 

I only need to sum at "concept" level, so with this is perfect.

Thanks a lot again!!!!!!!!