# SQL Rollup equivalent in MDX

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, rollup

I have a situation where I want to query multiple attributes (~8 altogether) and include subtotals. This is the kind of result that I want:

```
╔═══════╦═════════╦════════╦═════════╗
║ Attr1 ║  Attr2  ║ Attr3  ║ Measure ║
╠═══════╬═════════╬════════╬═════════╣
║ All   ║ All     ║ All    ║ 50%     ║
║ Foo   ║ All     ║ All    ║ 25%     ║
║ Bar   ║ All     ║ All    ║ 90%     ║
║ Foo   ║ Anna    ║ All    ║ 42%     ║
║ Foo   ║ Brian   ║ All    ║ 12%     ║
║ Bar   ║ Charles ║ All    ║ 10%     ║
║ Bar   ║ Dory    ║ All    ║ 112%    ║
║ Foo   ║ Anna    ║ Box    ║ 58%     ║
║ Foo   ║ Anna    ║ Circle ║ 13%     ║
║ ...   ║ ...     ║ ...    ║ ...     ║
╚═══════╩═════════╩════════╩═════════╝
```

Now, I can almost get there by doing something like this:

```
select
    {[Measures].[Measure]} on columns,
    nonempty({
        [Dim1].[Attr1].allmembers *
        [Dim2].[Attr2].allmembers *
        [Dim3].[Attr3].allmembers
    }) on rows
from [Cube]
```

However, this of course gets me a set that includes members that look like this:

```
╔═══════╦═════════╦════════╦═════════╗
║ Attr1 ║  Attr2  ║ Attr3  ║ Measure ║
╠═══════╬═════════╬════════╬═════════╣
║ Foo   ║ All     ║ Box    ║ 25%     ║
║ Bar   ║ All     ║ Circle ║ 90%     ║
║ Foo   ║ Anna    ║ Box    ║ 16%     ║
║ Bar   ║ Charles ║ Circle ║ 78%     ║
║ ...   ║ ...     ║ ...    ║ ...     ║
╚═══════╩═════════╩════════╩═════════╝
```

Which I don't want - I could live with them, except that with 8 dimensions it makes it go a bit crazy with the cross-join (it gives me an error about having a set with more than 4 billion tuples in it...). Now, if I were writing SQL I could do something simple like:

```
select
    Dim1.Attr1,
    Dim2.Attr2,
    Dim3.Attr3,
    Sum(Measures.Measure) as Measure
group by 
    Dim1.Attr1,
    Dim2.Attr2,
    Dim3.Attr3
with rollup
```

But I can't find an easy way to reproduce this in MDX. I can manually build each rollup level with something like this:

```
select
    {[Measures].[Measure]} on columns,
    nonempty(
        {
            {[Dim1].[Attr1].[All]} *
            {[Dim2].[Attr2].[All]} *
            {[Dim3].[Attr3].[All]}
        } +
        {
            {[Dim1].[Attr1].[Attr1].allmembers} *
            {[Dim2].[Attr2].[All]} *
            {[Dim3].[Attr3].[All]}
        } +
        {
            {[Dim1].[Attr1].[Attr1].allmembers} *
            {[Dim2].[Attr2].[Attr2].allmembers} *
            {[Dim3].[Attr3].[All]}
        } +
        {
            {[Dim1].[Attr1].[Attr1].allmembers} *
            {[Dim2].[Attr2].[Attr2].allmembers} *
            {[Dim3].[Attr3].[Attr3].allmembers}
        }
    ) on rows
from [Cube]
```

But that's already getting tedious with just three dimensions - specifying 9 groups of these is going to be nasty. So - is there a way of doing this concisely in MDX, or do I just have to go with the long-hand solution?

In terms of prior research, I've come across a bunch of answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10713166/781965) that say to use a `WITH MEMBER` statement to create a total row - but that's pointless for me, since it results in the same cross-join behaviour that I'm trying to avoid with the `allmembers` function.

**Edit:** this is the latest (sanitized) version of the code, including @Danylo's suggestion of `NonEmptyCrossJoin`:

```
NON EMPTY {
    NONEMPTYCROSSJOIN(
        {[Dim1].[Attribute].[All]} *
        {[Dim2].[Attribute].[All]} *
        {[Dim3].[Attribute].[All]} *
        {[Dim4].[Attribute].[All]} *
        {[Dim6].[Attribute].[All]} *
        {[Dim7].[Attribute].[All]} *
        {[Dim8].[Attribute].[All]} *
        {[Dim9].[Attribute].[All]} *
         [Dim0].[Attribute].[Attribute].ALLMEMBERS
    ) +
    NONEMPTYCROSSJOIN(
         [Dim1].[Attribute].[Attribute].ALLMEMBERS *
        {[Dim2].[Attribute].[All]} *
        {[Dim3].[Attribute].[All]} *
        {[Dim4].[Attribute].[All]} *
        {[Dim6].[Attribute].[All]} *
        {[Dim7].[Attribute].[All]} *
        {[Dim8].[Attribute].[All]} *
        {[Dim9].[Attribute].[All]} *
         [Dim0].[Attribute].[Attribute].ALLMEMBERS
    ) +
    NONEMPTYCROSSJOIN(
         [Dim1].[Attribute].[Attribute].ALLMEMBERS *
         [Dim2].[Attribute].[Attribute].ALLMEMBERS *
        {[Dim3].[Attribute].[All]} *
        {[Dim4].[Attribute].[All]} *
        {[Dim6].[Attribute].[All]} *
        {[Dim7].[Attribute].[All]} *
        {[Dim8].[Attribute].[All]} *
        {[Dim9].[Attribute].[All]} *
         [Dim0].[Attribute].[Attribute].ALLMEMBERS
    ) +

    ...

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using your measure as a second argument to the NonEmpty() function, to reduce the size of the cross-joined set?  This won't help with your "selective totals like WITH ROLLUP" problem, but might at least make the cross-join possible to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a way around using at least one cross-join (though putting the measure you're interested in into the NonEmpty() function - see comment - may help with the cross-join performance/out-of-memory problem).

The SQL ROLLUP-style totals exclude certain combinations of ALL and non-ALL, based on the order of the columns in your GROUP BY clause.  (In your example, this exclusion shows as a neat triangular pattern of ALLs in your result-set).  MDX doesn't do this: it doesn't really care about the order of the sets in your cross-join.

There's a way to do this by making MDX aware of this order.  It's a bit elaborate, but may be easier (or better-performing) than the long, "handbuilt" approach you tried:

```
WITH
MEMBER Measures.DimensionsAllPattern AS
    CASE WHEN [Dimension1].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Properties("LEVEL_NUMBER")="0" THEN "1" ELSE "0" END +
    CASE WHEN [Dimension2].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Properties("LEVEL_NUMBER")="0" THEN "1" ELSE "0" END +
    CASE WHEN [Dimension3].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Properties("LEVEL_NUMBER")="0" THEN "1" ELSE "0" END +
    ... etc up to dimension 8...
MEMBER AllPatternStrNum AS VBA!Cstr(VBA!CLng(Measures.DimensionsAllPattern))

SELECT 
{Measures.DimensionsAllPattern,Measures.AllPatternStrNum} ON 0,
FILTER
    (CROSSJOIN
        ([Dimension1].[Hierarchy].AllMembers,
         [Dimension2].[Hierarchy].AllMembers,
         .... etc
         )
     ,
     (Measures.AllPatternStrNum="0") OR
     (Measures.AllPatternStrNum=VBA!String(VBA!Len(Measures.AllPatternStrNum),"1"))
     )
ON 1
FROM TheCube
```

What this is doing is:

1. For each combination of members from the dimensions, building a string corresponding to the pattern of All/Non-All, based on a specified order of dimensions.  For example, {All,Something,All,Something} would be coded as 1010.
2. A second calculated member converts this measure to a number and then back to a string: so 1010 would end up as 1010, but 0011 would end up as 11 (simple way of stripping off leading zeros)
3. The cross-joined set is then filtered according to this second member.  It must either be equivalent to 0 (no ALL values at all), or be a string of 1s as long as its own length.

(Note I haven't included any NonEmpty stuff in my example, or the measure you actually want to see).

You may need to do wrap the filtered set in an ORDER(set,something,BASC) to get it looking the way you want.

Comment: Forgot to include non-empty in my example (though I'm not including a second argument to it, so that may help). I *think* that that's the thing that's complaining about the 4 billion tuples though, so the solution in your answer might be the way to go - it's pretty clever! I'll be back here to accept if it works :)

Comment: Well, it almost works - I got it successfully working for 5 layers, but much more than that and it starts complaining that `The Auto Exist operation is exceeding the permitted memory limit and is being canceled.` Unless I get a better response over the weekend though, I'll accept your answer since it technically does the job (and is nicer syntactically than the long-hand in my question)

Comment: Sounds like this could simply be a problem with the size of the cross-joined set, independent of our attempts to get a ROLLUP-like set out of it.  Does it work if you simply cross-join the 8 dimensions and show the measure, without any of the clever stuff?

Comment: Not if I include the `all` members - only with the children. That, however, reduces the size pretty tremendously, which is why I was looking for a solution that could perform the "trickiness" internally, rather than as a post-query filter.

Comment: I get it - something like the way SQL GROUP BY only looks at what actually exists, and then does the ROLLUP afterwards, avoiding enormous cross-joined sets completely.  I suspect that SSAS's internal AutoExists function works surprisingly well - as long as you _don't_ include the All members, which turn the operation into something closer to a full cross-join.  Never thought about this before.

Answer (score 2):

One way of accelerating this type of MDX is to not do it all in one step.  The same is true of SQL.  Use Subcubes.

```
CREATE SUBCUBE [CubeName] AS 
 SELECT {SomeMeasures} ON COLUMNS, 
{ 
    CROSSJOIN({Field1.ALLMEMBERS}, 
             {Field2.ALLMEMBERS},
                  More as needed                
                                 ) }
ON ROWS 
FROM [CubeName]
```

Rather quaintly, the SubCube should have the same name as the cube/perspective you are using.

You can create as many subcubes as you need, all having the same name, then do a final SELECT statement from the narrowed down cube.

Drop the subcube afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently posted an article about that. In order to avoid cross join memory issues I'd recommend to wrap sets with the `NonEmptyCrossJoin` function. Read more here: http://blog.soft-prestidigitation.com/the-totals-and-the-nonemptycrossjoin-function.html

Comment: That's cool - we did wind up going with the long-hand union approach as we could get moderate performance out of it - I'll try this out in it to see if it improves the performance though, because that would be helpful. It doesn't let us do it without writing a massive query, but it's looking more and more like that's not going to happen. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this didn't improve the performance significantly - I'm not sure why, but I guess it's a situational thing.

Comment: I've included the latest version in the question - though I swapped out all the dimension/attribute names

Comment: Please read my blog post more closely. I've mentioned the parameter for number of attributes. Can you show me the full code? It may be your real query, but it's important to see from the very begging to the ending, including a select section. Try to reduce number of attributes and test the performance. I see two problems:
1. your MDX isn't great again and you miss something. 2. It's impossible due to the huge query result.

Comment: The query itself is really just `SELECT [Measures].[X] on Columns, ... on Rows from [Cube]` - it's not a tricky query in any respect except this. I am coming to the conclusion that this is just not feasible with such a large data set. Reducing the number of attributes does have a fairly immediate effect on performance (using a number of different techniques), so I think I'm just being overly optimistic here.

Comment: I'd pick one member from the densest attribute and check if it works well. If performance is slow that means your NonEmpty optimisation doesn't work. MDX is really tight work in that case.